# Type of 'variablename' cannot be inferred from an expression containing 'Ycor' - Error

Tags: .net, vb.net, for-loop

I came from C# background now im trying to write on VB NET.

I wrote a few rows in VB NET:

```
For Xcor = 0 To bmp.Width Step (bmp.Width / 10)

        For Ycor = 0 To Ycor <= bmp.Height Step 1


            pixelColor = bmp.GetPixel(Xcor, Ycor)

            hue = pixelColor.GetHue()
            saturation = pixelColor.GetSaturation()

            If ((hue > hueMin) AndAlso (hue < hueMax)) Then

                bmp.SetPixel(Xcor, Ycor, Color.Black)

            End If
          Next
      Next
```

In this row i get:

```
 For Ycor = 0 To Ycor <= bmp.Height Step 1
```

this error:

**Type of 'Ycor' cannot be inferred from an expression containing 'Ycor'.**

Any idea how to fix the code?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Given that this isn’t your first question about this, I’d strongly suggest that you get a VB book to learn about the syntax basics, or at the very least go through the keywords reference on MSDN and look at a few code samples there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just meant:

```
For Ycor = 0 To bmp.Height Step 1
```

Or equivalently, as per comments:

```
For Ycor = 0 To bmp.Height
```

[VB `For` loops](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z06z1kb.aspx) specify their bounds, not conditions. (Look at your `Xcor` loop, for example.)

Comment: And you can just omit `Step 1` as "If not specified, step defaults to 1."